# Call By Name for List's Elements?

Tags: scala

The following function, `f`, takes an argument in a call by-name manner:

```
scala> def f(xs: => List[Int]) = xs
f: (xs: => List[Int])List[Int]
```

Then, I tried to define a function with a List of call by-name arguments:

```
scala> def f(xs: List[=> Int]) = xs
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '=>' found.
def f(xs: List[=> Int]) = xs
               ^
```

But that failed.

I could do:

```
scala> def f(xs: List[Function0[Int]]) = xs
f: (xs: List[() => Int])List[() => Int]
```

But, is it possible to use call by-name on the arguments of a `List` using the `=>` syntax?

Comment: `Function0` is not the same thing as `=> Int`, but it's the same thing has `() => Int`, the last one is not a call by name parameter, it's a function that takes a unit and returns an int.

Comment: This wouldn't really make any sense because the elements of a list are strictly evaluated anyway. `=>` is just syntax—you can't really abstract over it.

Comment: Just because of curiosity: if it would be possible, wouldn't it be just a Stream?